# CSS fixed div over a list menu

Tags: css, overlap, css-position

I have a list menu like:

```
<div id="my_menu">
    <ul class="my_horizontal_menu">
        <li class="nav_1">
            <a>my nav1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_2">
            <a>my nav2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have other div after to display the content, according the click on the menu:

```
<div id="my_container_1">
    some data
</div>
<div id="my_container_2">
    some data
</div>
```

I use some simple JQuery code to display the right menu and the container. Everything works fine.
Now, I have a fixed div into a container:

```
<div id="my_container_2">
    <table>...some data...</table>
    <div id="my_fixed_div">
    </div>
</div>
```

The fixed div `my_fixed_div` uses some CSS to be fixed when the page is scrolling and it works. The problem is this fixed div overlapping the menu when the user scrolls:
[image: Fixed DIV overlaps the menu]

Do you know how to solve this problem? Display the fixed div always over all the page content? I tried with `z-index:1000` but i doesn't work...

Comment: Could you create an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: not really because I simplified my problem: the whole page is more complicated and has more elements of course. Maybe I was not clear but I tried my best to explain, including the screenshot. So, the problem is that the menu is displayed over the fixed div, even if this one (the fixed div) has a z-index higher (than all other elements: you can see, it's displayed over all other elements, except this menu).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem according to your description, and this is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WyxuW/). Maybe your problem was caused by something you didn't mention. That's why I expected to see your code, at least an example which can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a lower z-index value to have it render behind the other elements

Comment: I set a higher z-index to the fixed div: it should be ok but actually not...That's what you meant?

Comment: and I want the fixed div OVER all the elements! Not behind